# C++ Static Struct Member Variable Efficiency

Tags: c++, static, member-variables

I wrote a class that contains 5 static member variables.  I can improve the organization of my code if I group the 5 members variables together in a struct, then statically declare the struct in my class.  However, would the extra dereferencing to access each variable reduce the efficiency of my code?  I care about organization, but I don't want to sacrifice performance since the efficiency of my code matters and two of variables stored in the struct are frequently accessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would not be any "extra dereferencing", and no performance difference at all between the two approaches (except *maybe* extremely minor locality/cache hits if your `static` objects are allocated far from each other; which is highly unlikely).

You could have determined this by measuring it.

Comment: Even more easily by viewing the assembly and seeing it was identical (or at least the same number and types of instructions).

Comment: @NirFriedman: That's only "easy" if you understand the assembly language in question or, indeed, any of them.